# SQLAlchemy sum function with bounds

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, window-functions

In `sqlalchemy` (`postgresql` DB), I would like to create a bounded sum function, for lack of a better term. The goal is to create a running total within a defined range.

Currently, I have something that works great for calculating a running total without the bounds. Something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

foos = (
    db.query(
        Foo.id,
        Foo.points,
        Foo.timestamp,
        func.sum(Foo.points).over(order_by=Foo.timestamp).label('running_total')
    )
    .filter(...)
    .all()
)
```

However, I would like to be able to bound this running total to always be within a specific range, let's say `[-100, 100]`. So we would get something like this (see `running_total`):

```
{'timestamp': 1, 'points': 75, 'running_total': 75}
{'timestamp': 2, 'points': 50, 'running_total': 100}
{'timestamp': 3, 'points': -100, 'running_total': 0}
{'timestamp': 4, 'points': -50, 'running_total': -50}
{'timestamp': 5, 'points': -75, 'running_total': -100}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no built-in aggregate can help you achieve your expected output with window function calls.

You could get the expected output with manually calculating the rows one-by-one with a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive t as (
  (select   *, points running_total
   from     foo
   order by timestamp
   limit    1)
  union all
  (select   foo.*, least(greatest(t.running_total + foo.points, -100), 100)
   from     foo, t
   where    foo.timestamp > t.timestamp
   order by foo.timestamp
   limit    1)
)
select timestamp,
       points,
       running_total
from   t;
```

Unfortunately, this will be very hard to achieve with SQLAlchemy.

Your other option is, to [write a custom aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html) for your specific needs, like:

```
create function bounded_add(int_state anyelement, next_value anyelement, next_min anyelement, next_max anyelement)
  returns anyelement
  immutable
  language sql
as $func$
  select least(greatest(int_state + next_value, next_min), next_max);
$func$;

create aggregate bounded_sum(next_value anyelement, next_min anyelement, next_max anyelement)
(
    sfunc    = bounded_add,
    stype    = anyelement,
    initcond = '0'
);
```

With this, you just need to replace your call to `sum` to be a call to `bounded_sum`:

```
select timestamp,
       points,
       bounded_sum(points, -100.0, 100.0) over (order by timestamp) running_total
from   foo;
```

This latter solution will probably scale better too.

http://rextester.com/LKCUK93113

Answer (score 2):

**note** my initial answer is wrong, see edit below:

In raw sql, you'd do this using [greatest & least functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST).

Something like this:

```
LEAST(GREATEST(SUM(myfield) OVER (window_clause), lower_bound), upper_bound)
```

sqlalchemy expression language allows one two write that almost identically

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as dec
base = dec.declarative_base()

class Foo(base):
  __tablename__ = 'foo'
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  points = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
  timestamp = sa.Column('tstamp', sa.Integer)

upper_, lower_ = 100, -100
win_expr = func.sum(Foo.points).over(order_by=Foo.timestamp)
bound_expr = sa.func.least(sa.func.greatest(win_expr, lower_), upper_).label('bounded_running_total')

stmt = sa.select([Foo.id, Foo.points, Foo.timestamp, bound_expr])

str(stmt)
# prints output:
# SELECT foo.id, foo.points, foo.tstamp, least(greatest(sum(foo.points) OVER (ORDER BY foo.tstamp), :greatest_1), :least_1) AS bounded_running_total 
# FROM foo'


# alternatively using session.query you can also fetch results

from sqlalchemy.orm sessionmaker
DB = sessionmaker()
db = DB()
foos_stmt = dm.query(Foo.id, Foo.points, Foo.timestamp, bound_expr).filter(...)
str(foos_stmt)
# prints output:
# SELECT foo.id, foo.points, foo.tstamp, least(greatest(sum(foo.points) OVER (ORDER BY foo.tstamp), :greatest_1), :least_1) AS bounded_running_total 
# FROM foo'

foos = foos_stmt.all()
```

**EDIT** As user @pozs points out in the comments, the above does not produce the intended results.

Two alternate approaches have been presented by @pozs. Here, I've adapted the first, recursive query approach, constructed via sqlalchemy.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as dec
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
base = dec.declarative_base()

class Foo(base):
  __tablename__ = 'foo'
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  points = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
  timestamp = sa.Column('tstamp', sa.Integer)

upper_, lower_ = 100, -100
t = sa.select([
  Foo.timestamp,
  Foo.points,
  Foo.points.label('bounded_running_sum')
]).order_by(Foo.timestamp).limit(1).cte('t', recursive=True)

t_aliased = orm.aliased(t, name='ta')

bounded_sum = t.union_all(
  sa.select([
    Foo.timestamp,
    Foo.points,
    sa.func.greatest(sa.func.least(Foo.points + t_aliased.c.bounded_running_sum, upper_), lower_)
  ]).order_by(Foo.timestamp).limit(1)
)
stmt = sa.select([bounded_sum])

# inspect the query:
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
print(stmt.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), 
                   compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
# prints output: 
# WITH RECURSIVE t(tstamp, points, bounded_running_sum) AS
# ((SELECT foo.tstamp, foo.points, foo.points AS bounded_running_sum
# FROM foo ORDER BY foo.tstamp
# LIMIT 1) UNION ALL (SELECT foo.tstamp, foo.points, greatest(least(foo.points + ta.bounded_running_sum, 100), -100) AS greatest_1
# FROM foo, t AS ta ORDER BY foo.tstamp
# LIMIT 1))
# SELECT t.tstamp, t.points, t.bounded_running_sum
# FROM t
```

I used this [link from the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte) as a reference to construct the above, which also highlights how one may use the session instead to work with recursive CTEs

This would be the *pure sqlalchemy* method to generate the required results.

The 2nd approach suggested by @pozs could also be used via sqlalchemy.

The solution would have to be a variant of this [section from the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html#further-examples)

Comment: This does not produce the required results

Comment: @pozs, you're right. should i delete the answer, or keep it for historical reasons?

Comment: or you can correct it. if you know how to do it better / differently / in SQLAlchemy, I'm interested too.

Comment: @pozs, I'll take a crack at it. I know that we can define recursive ctes via sqlalchemy, so that would be the `pure sqlalchemy way`. its also possible to define custom sql constructs, so, once the `bounded_sum` function is defined in the database, we can have a special python function to use from the application